# Fetching netsed multiple values using jdbc in multiple joins

Tags: java, jdbc

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(
      "select distinct ur.*,al.*,im.* from  user as ur  "    
   + "left join album as al "
   + "on ur.id=al.aid "
   + "left join images as im "
   + "on al.id=im.album_id ");
```

Here One user can have multiple albums and each album can have multiple images.
I want to fetch all data from ablove query.
I have written following code

```
List<User> uList=new ArrayList<User>();
 while (rs.next()) {

  User u = new User(rs.getLong("ur.id"), rs.getString("ur.fname"), rs.getString("ur.lname"), null);
 Album al = new Album(rs.getLong("al.id"), rs.getString("al.name"));
 Images pi = new Images(rs.getLong("im.image_id"), rs.getString("im.img_desc"), rs.getString("im.sm_pic_path"));
Set<Images> piSet = new HashSet<Images>();
piSet.add(pi);
al.setImages(piSet);
Set<Album> alSet = new HashSet<Album>();
alSet.add(al);
u.setAlbums(alSet);
uList.add(u);
}
```

Here How can we ensure that all images are attached with correct Album.

Comment: Sorry i did not get your question here. You r query ensures that  all images are attached with correct Album as first joined album with user and them images with album. Whats the issue here ?

Comment: I am not sure will it always return correct output.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to deal with this would be to **order** your SQL:

```
 ORDER BY ur.id, al.id, im.image_id
```

Once you have that, you know that all albums for one user as well as all images for one album will be in consecutive rows - so you can simply switch `currentUser` and `currentAlbum` values like this:

```
User curentUser = new User(-1); //User with ID -1
Album currentAlbum = new Album (-1); //Album with ID -1
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(); //List of all users
while(rs.next()) {
   User u = new User(rs.getLong("ur.id"), rs.getString("ur.fname"), rs.getString("ur.lname"), null);
   //CurrentUser has changed!
   if(u.getId() != currentUser.getId()) {
     currentUser = u;
     //Add to list of users
     users.add(u);
   }
   Album al = new Album(rs.getLong("al.id"), rs.getString("al.name"));
   //Current Album has changed?
   if(currentAlbum.getId() != al.getId()) {
     currentAlbum = al;
      //Add this as album to user
     currentUser.addAlbum(al);
   }
   Images pi = new Images(rs.getLong("im.image_id"), rs.getString("im.img_desc"), rs.getString("im.sm_pic_path"));
   //Add this image to currentAlbum
   currentAlbum.addImage(pi);
}
```

Your `Set<Images>` will need to become a member of `Album` and your `Set<Album>` will need to become a member of `User` for this to work - but afterwards you get a fine object oriented list of `User`s with their `Album`s and `Images` in place.